# Binding only gets applied to source when event is invoked

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have a custom control that has a dependency property. When SetValue is called on the Dependency property, nothing happens unless SetValue is called after a UI event gets fired. Look at the example below to see what I mean.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemDictionaryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemDictionary", typeof(Dictionary<string, Control>), typeof(ListBoxEx),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Dictionary<string, Control>(),     FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender, OnItemDictionaryPropertyChanged));

    private Dictionary<string, Control> itemDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Control>();

    private static void OnItemDictionaryPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var test = (ListBoxEx)d;
        test.ItemDictionary = (Dictionary<string, object>)e.NewValue;
       // test.GetBindingExpression(ItemDictionaryProperty).UpdateSource();
    }

    public override void EndInit()
    {
        itemDictionary.Clear();
        foreach (var item in this.Items)
            itemDictionary.Add((item as Control).Tag.ToString(), item as Control);

        this.ItemDictionary = itemDictionary; // This doesn't

        base.EndInit();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Control> ItemDictionary
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<string, Control>)GetValue(ItemDictionaryProperty); }
        set  { SetValue(ItemDictionaryProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        itemDictionary.Clear();
        foreach (var item in this.Items)
            itemDictionary.Add((item as Control).Tag.ToString(), item as Control);

        ItemDictionary = itemDictionary; // This works
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }
```

When `ItemDictionary` is updated in `EndInit`. The binding property doesn't get updated. 
As soon as I call it in an event method, then all of a sudden my changes effect the source.

I did a little test to see if my bindings were being created being `EndInit` but setting the property equal to null in my viewmodels'  constructor. So even though the binding works and it invokes `OnItemDictionaryPropertyChanged`. Nothing in the source changes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it could be an application lifecycle problem.  Perhaps EndInit() gets called before `ItemDictionaryProperty` gets set up with your `new Dictionary<string, Control>()` in the `FrameworkPropertyMetaData`.  EndInit() appears to be related to only the graphical part of the control.  [MSDN for ISupportInitialize.EndInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.endinit(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try using the `Loaded` event.  [Info on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx)

Comment: So would there be any way for me to invoke it as soon as the application starts?

Comment: I'm assuming `ListBoxEx` is custom class of yours that inherits from `ListBox`. Try using the Loaded event. Info on MSDN (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx)